# Dynamically (automatically) change the "download folder" in Safari

Tags: safari-extensions, safari

[Saft](http://haoli.dnsalias.com/saft/) -- the (now seemingly defunct as of Safari 5.1) Safari plugin -- had the ability to change the name of the download folder (and create said folder if it didn't already exist) that Safari uses (e.g., by creating a name based on the date).  This was incredibly useful for decluttering/ordering my downloads.

Is there any comparable feature in a supported Safari extension (for Safari 5.1)?

P.S.  I know I can create a cron job to do this after the fact, but that seems kludgey and prone to errors because of file timestamps, automatically unpacked ZIP/tar/cpio files, etc.

Comment: I've not yet used it, but just found that glims (http://www.machangout.com/)  advertises this feature (and that it is supported on Safari 5.1).

Anyone with experience/alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the Glims Safari Plugin (ver1.0b29) in Safari 5.1 (OSX Lion), which has the feature "Create dated folder for downloaded files".

[image: Create dated folder for downloaded files in Glims]

Comment: Apparently glims is not supported on El Capitan (10.11)

Comment: Im on El Capitan 10.11.6 and Glims is still working with Safari 10.0.2. Some features don't seem to be working, but the Dated Folders part is working fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own "S/W Downloads" folder and put it in the Dock.  I have it show as List, and there is an option to display by date, the newest being on top.

If that is sufficient, there is no need for Saft.

Answer (score 0):

With the demise of Glims support (beyond Mavericks?), I broke down and wrote a cron job to automatically change the default download folder of Safari.

The crontab entries look like:

```
@reboot $HOME/bin/rotateDownloads
0 0 * * * $HOME/bin/rotateDownloads
```

The contents of `rotateDownloads` looks like:

```
#! /bin/ksh

NEWPATH=$HOME/downloads/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
mkdir -p ${NEWPATH} && defaults write com.apple.Safari DownloadsPath ${NEWPATH}`#! /bin/ksh
OLDPATH=$HOME/downloads/$(date -v -1d +%Y-%m-%d)
rmdir ${OLDPATH} > /dev/null 2>&1  # remove old directory if empty
```

This seems to work on El Capitan (MacOS 10.11.4) with Safari 9.1.

Edit: **Safari 13 seems to have broken this.**

Answer (score -1):

just Control click the download link

Comment: and then do what?